# Reusing code ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a module in my project in lib/. it's content is like this :

```
module Search
  module Score

    def get_score
      return 'something'
    end

  end    
end
```

This Search has many different modules I need to use Score. I realize I need to add require in my model (I'm trying to use this from model). So here is my code (model) :

```
require 'search'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def get_user_score
    #tried this :
    p Search::Score.get_score #error
    #this as well
    score_instance = Score.new #error
    score = Search::Score.get_score # error undefined method `get_score'
  end

end
```

So how do I reuse the code I have in other class (module)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get it working you can either mix the module into your class:

```
require 'search'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Search::Score

  def get_user_score
    p get_score # => "something"
  end
end
```

Or you can define the method inside your module similar to class methods:

```
module Search
  module Score
    def self.get_score
      return 'something'
    end
  end    
end
```

If you do that, you can call `get_score` like expected:

```
require 'search'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def get_user_score
    p Search::Score.get_score # => "something"
  end
end
```

See [this tutorial](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html) for a more in depth explanation about modules in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

First, see "[Best Practices for reusing code between controllers in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128450/best-practices-for-reusing-code-between-controllers-in-ruby-on-rails)".

About reuse code as a module, take a look at "[Rethinking code reuse with Modularity for Ruby](http://www.agileweboperations.com/rethinking-code-reuse-with-modularity-for-ruby)".

Answer (score 0):

`Search::Score` is a module and not a class, so `Score.new` will not work.

You can try to change the signature of the `get_score` function to `self.get_score`.

Answer (score 0):

**"Modules are crippled classes"**

Modules are like crippled classes in Ruby. If you look into the inheritance chain you see that a Class actually inherits from Module.

Module cannot be instanciated. So the call to .new is not working.

What you CAN do however is to specify your method as a 'class' method (I know I said it is not a class...)

So you would add a self in front like this:

```
module Search
  module Score

    def self.get_score
      return 'something'
    end

  end    
end
```

Then you can call this method as a class method like you tried in your code example

Comment: I wouldn't call them anything like a crippled class. They are a very powerful feature with a great reason for existing and are key to what makes Ruby a cool language. Comparable and Enumerable are powerful modules that demonstrate what is good about modules.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `def self.get_score` in the above answers, there is also `extend self`, like so:

```rb
module Search
  module Score
    extend self

    def get_score
      return 'something'
    end
  end    
end
```

and `module_function`:

```rb
module Search
  module Score
    module_function

    def get_score
      return 'something'
    end
  end    
end
```

The latter is actually the preferred method in RuboCop [(source)](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#module_function), though in practice I personally have not seen it so often.