# Rails call same action code from two controllers (with a small difference)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, url-routing

I have two different routes that need to output the same page with only minor differences (title, open graph tags, etc.)

routes.rb

```
match 'referral/:ref' => 'referral#home'
root :to => "home#index"
```

home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @passion    = Passion.new
    @workshop   = Workshop.new
    @regions    = Region.where("workshops_count > 0").order("name ASC")
    @categories = Category.where("passions_count > 0 AND parent_id IS NULL").order("name ASC")
  end
end
```

I'm not willing to copy the exact same code from the HomeController to the ReferralController and I don't want a redirect, because the title and OG tags must be different (in order to have a special referral title when the page is shared)

With an express.js app (which I'm more familiar with), I would add a middleware in the referral route and then call the HomeController#index action. So everything would be done at the routing level.

What's the idiomatic approach in Rails?

Thanks,
Laurent

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: Generally we use rails in Thin controller Fat model , so if at all the code related to models then write the common logic in models and call from there  in both controllers

Comment: @ratnakar question updated with some code. I understand the thin-controller / fat-model thing, but here we're actually loading "reference data" (to populate search filters, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would add a middleware in the referral route and then call the HomeController#index action. So everything would be done at the routing level.

Don't fall into the trap of sacrificing clarity for cleverness. This can be very unintuitive and frustrating for people (including yourself) coming onto your project at a later stage. This approach also becomes subject to some arbitrary decisions like which controller action gets routed to which?

The best code is the simplest solution that still clearly communicates your intentions to a reader. For this reason, I prefer to use plain old Ruby objects where possible. You can extract the logic into a simple query object, for example:

```
# app/queries/home_query.rb
class HomeQuery
  attr_reader :passion, :workshop, :regions, :categories

  def initialize
    @passion    = Passion.new
    @workshop   = Workshop.new
    @regions    = Region.where("workshops_count > 0").order("name ASC")
    @categories = Category.where("passions_count > 0 AND parent_id IS NULL").order("name ASC")
  end
end
```

Then use it to pass values from your controller action:

```
# app/controllers/home_controller.rb
def index
  @stuff = HomeQuery.new
end
```

And in your view, you can use `@stuff.passion`, `@stuff.workshop`, etc. to access your stuff.

It is DRY, its intention is clear, and it uses common Ruby constructs that most people are familiar with.

Comment: Thanks, I like the aproach. It encapsulates the work needed for the home page in a very explicit but concise way.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify what template/layout to render in the controller action. For example in `referral#home` controller action:

```
render :template => 'home/index'
```

This assumes that there is not a lot of logic in the controller action (which is best practice in Rails).

If there is common setup code for each action, then you can extract it into a module and include it in both controllers:

```
 module CommonFunctionality
   def set_ivars
     @passion    = Passion.new
     @workshop   = Workshop.new
     @regions    = Region.where("workshops_count > 0").order("name ASC")
     @categories = Category.where("passions_count > 0 AND parent_id IS NULL").order("name ASC")      
   end
 end

 class HomeController
   include CommonFunctionality
   def index
     set_ivars
   end
 end

 class ReferralController
   include CommonFunctionality
   def index
     set_ivars
     render :template => 'home/index'
   end
 end
```

This is not the only possible solution, there are many ways of abstracting common code in Ruby.

Comment: Answer with moving code to application_controller is much more `rails way`

Comment: I wouldn't put this kind of code in the application controller, it doesn't make sense that code that is specific to two actions would be available to all controllers that derive from application controller. using modules allows you to categorise things better.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper method which performs all of the common action steps and then invoke that method from each controller action to DRY it up.

So in `application_controller.rb`:

```
def setfoo
  @foo = "setting foo"
end
```

Then in your controller actions:

```
def oneaction
  setfoo
end

def anotheraction
  setfoo
end
```

Credit to this outstanding post [Best Practices for reusing code between controllers in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128450/best-practices-for-reusing-code-between-controllers-in-ruby-on-rails)