# How to link controllers in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Sometimes I need from one controller to use operations from another controller. What I do now is instantiate it and use its operation, but it gives me the feeling that it is not correct what I do, so I have been taught that there can not be several instances of the same controller.

**What is the best practice?** Thank you very much.

Comment: this question answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128450/best-practices-for-reusing-code-between-controllers-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you link controllers
Make the method .`self`

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def self.get_details(data)
  end
end
```

And then:

```
class ChildrenController < ApplicationController
  def set_details        
    TestController.get_details(data)
  end
end
```

other option to create library module

## lib/common_stuff.rb

```
module CommonStuff
  def common_thing
    # code
  end
end
```

## app/controllers/my_controller.rb

```
require 'common_stuff'
class MyController < ApplicationController
  include CommonStuff
  # has access to common_thing
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Good practice in Rails is to move common logic to service/module/lib/gem. If operations you need are specific only to controllers then you define abstract controller and inherit your controllers from that. Just like you do with `ApplicationController`.